# Foggy text and freezing in Firefox over XPRA

Tags: firefox, video-streaming, xpra

I'm forwarding Firefox over XPRA and the text is blurry. Also, the application freezes often for several seconds, even though there's plenty of system resources to run Firefox. I tried playing with the `--min-speed` and `--min-quality` XPRA flags to no effect.

How do I get Firefox to work in XPRA?

Tested with the latest XPRA (4.4) on an Ubuntu Docker container.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by changing the video encoder that XPRA uses. Firefox is blurry and freezes when you use the default encoding (`--encoding=auto`), but if you add the `--encodings=jpeg` flag, then the text is no longer blurry and Firefox no longer freezes.

**Important!** Notice that I set `--encodings=jpeg`, and not `--encoding=jpeg`. For some reason, the former works, and the latter doesn't.

**Warning: This can cause other bugs**. While Firefox worked perfectly, I also tested out `--encodings=jpeg` on Wireshark. For some reason, Wireshark's top menu dropdown no longer works properly (is invisible but still clickable) when you specify `--encodings=jpeg`.

My final solution was to switch between `--encodings=jpeg` and `--encodings=all` depending on whether I needed to forward Firefox or Wireshark.

Comment: Don't follow this terrible advice.
Messing up with `encodings` is not how you tune xpra. This has been documented again and again through the years, yet people still think they know better.

Comment: Can you offer a better solution, then? I'd love to hear it and try it out.

Comment: Not without more details: https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/wiki/Reporting-Bugs